# Expected 'collections.Iterable', got Optional[list] instead

Tags: list, python-2.7, pycharm

I received this error in Pycharm Community Edition 5.0.3 today and was wondering whether it was just something I'm doing wrong/not realizing, or if it is a PyCharm lint issue. The code to reproduce the error is

```
mylist = list()

# fill mylist, or do nothing here, either way the error persists

if mylist:
    # if something in the list...
    mylist.append(2)
else:
    # list is empty, add something
    mylist.append(1)

# warning at the loop here
for val in mylist:
    print val
```

Is this because it's thinking that mylist is a union of type ?

Comment: It seems to think `mylist` could be `None`.

Comment: Yeah looks like you're right, putting an if mylist: before the loop will get rid of the error.

Comment: I filed the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional[list]` is a [`typing` annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) that signals PyCharm found `mylist` to be either `None` or a `list` object.

This appears to be caused by the `if mylist:` test; I'd say this is PyCharm making an incorrect inference here, since you clearly set `mylist` to a `list` instance only one line before. `if` tests for emptiness, not if the object is `None`.

This is a bug, filed with the PyCharm project as [issue PY-21897](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21897), and fixed in PyCharm verson 2017.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you place something like this:

```
""":rtype: list"""
```

in the docstring for the function that produces your list, that should make pycharm realize you really are expecting a list.